# Mac Mini Sleeping When Idle

Tags: mojave, pmset

We are having some issues with 2 Mac minis running Mojave.  They go to sleep after a couple of minutes the user logs out.

We tried playing with the `pmset` settings without luck

Here are my current settings

```
~/Documents/vc:$ pmset -g

System-wide power settings:

Currently in use:

standby 1

Sleep On Power Button 1

womp 1

autorestart 0

hibernatefile /var/vm/sleepimage

proximitywake 1

powernap 0

gpuswitch 2

networkoversleep 0

disksleep 0

standbydelayhigh 86400

sleep 0

hibernatemode 3

ttyskeepawake 1

displaysleep 0

tcpkeepalive 1

highstandbythreshold 50

standbydelaylow 86400
```

Does anyone knows how to keep them awake 24/7?  Our monitoring systems complain about the minis being unreachable.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are power settings?  Go to *Settings → Energy Saver*  What do you have set?

Comment: I added a screenshot of my Power Settings to the post

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors in your power settings.

- `hibernatemode 3`.  3 is the default for *portables*; since you have a Mac mini, this is incorrect; it should be 0 (default) for desktops.
- `standby 1`.  If you don't want your machine to go into standby at all, this should be set to 0
- `autopoweroff` seems to be missing. This should also be set to 0 as it's enabled by default.

Issue the command

```
pmset -a hibernatemode 0 standby 0 autopoweroff 0
```

Comment: Same issue with this settings: $ pmset -g
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 standby              0
 Sleep On Power Button 1
 womp                 1
 autorestart          0
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 proximitywake        1
 powernap             0
 gpuswitch            2
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            0
 standbydelayhigh     86400
 sleep                0
 hibernatemode        0
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         0
 tcpkeepalive         1
 highstandbythreshold 50
 standbydelaylow      86400